# Can't move Xcode UIButtons with touchesbegan

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, touchesbegan

I am trying to move a button, here is my code. I am not even getting the "fires1" output when I try to move my button. It just gets pressed and doesn't move. I've searched around and I always get the same answers, which I have already applied to my code.

Anyone have any idea why my buttons won't move?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"%@",@"fires1");
    if ([touches count] == 1) {
        // one finger
        CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
        for (UIButton *iView in self.letterButtons) {
           // if ([iView isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                if (touchPoint.x > iView.frame.origin.x &&
                    touchPoint.x < iView.frame.origin.x + iView.frame.size.width &&
                    touchPoint.y > iView.frame.origin.y &&
                    touchPoint.y < iView.frame.origin.y + iView.frame.size.height)
                {
                    self.dragObject = iView;
                    self.touchOffset = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x - iView.frame.origin.x,
                                                   touchPoint.y - iView.frame.origin.y);
                    self.homePosition = CGPointMake(iView.frame.origin.x,
                                                    iView.frame.origin.y);
                    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.dragObject];
                    NSLog(@"%@",@"works!");

                }
            //}
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGRect newDragObjectFrame = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - touchOffset.x,
                                           touchPoint.y - touchOffset.y,
                                           self.dragObject.frame.size.width,
                                           self.dragObject.frame.size.height);
    self.dragObject.frame = newDragObjectFrame;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    if (touchPoint.x > self.dropTarget.frame.origin.x &&
        touchPoint.x < self.dropTarget.frame.origin.x + self.dropTarget.frame.size.width &&
        touchPoint.y > self.dropTarget.frame.origin.y &&
        touchPoint.y < self.dropTarget.frame.origin.y + self.dropTarget.frame.size.height )
    {
       // self.dropTarget.currentTitle = self.dragObject.currentTitle;

    }
    self.dragObject.frame = CGRectMake(self.homePosition.x, self.homePosition.y,
                                       self.dragObject.frame.size.width,
                                       self.dragObject.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: I think you are using auto layout! It doesn't work with autolayout.

Comment: Try unchecking the autolayout option from XIB and run again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you implementing touches began if you're using UIButtons? 
Remove your touches began method and link all your buttons on TouchDown event to this IBAction

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{

  self.dragObject = (UIButton*)sender;
  self.homePosition = CGPointMake(sender.frame.origin.x,
                                                sender.frame.origin.y);
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.dragObject];

}
```

Adjust your touceshMoved method like

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
     self.dragObject.center = currentPoint;
    }
```

Make your touchesEnded method look like this

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 BOOL btnAIntersectsWithBtnB = CGRectIntersectsRect(self.dragTarget.frame,self.dropObject.frame);
 if(btnAIntersectsWithBtnB)
 {
   self.dropTarget.currentTitle = self.dragObject.currentTitle;
 }
 self.dragObject.frame = CGRectMake(self.homePosition.x, self.homePosition.y,
                                       self.dragObject.frame.size.width,
                                       self.dragObject.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm getting `Property 'frame' not found on object of type '__strong id'` I'm trying to move a (A)button to another (B)button. If they hover, the `currentTitle` of (B)button, gets changed to whatever (A)buttons `currentTitle` is. The code I posted worked for images. Thanks for helping

Comment: I have edited the code. Please take a look. If the only purpose is to check if btnA intersects with btnB then you can use my code above. Let me know if it helps